# How can I build NSInvocation for the Class method?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to build the invocation using NSClassFromString and NSSelectorFromString for the class method and the selector. 
          I tried to build invocation in the following way:

```
NSMethodSignature *signature;
NSInvocation *inv;

Class targetClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSString");
SEL selector   = NSSelectorFromString(@"stringWithString:");
id arg = @"argument";

Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, selector);
```

// why is the method nil when I run the code?

```
struct objc_method_description* desc = method_getDescription(method);

if (desc == NULL || desc->name == NULL){
    return nil;
}

signature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:desc->types];
inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[inv setSelector:selector];
[inv setArgument:&arg atIndex:2];
[inv invoke];

__autoreleasing id returnObj;    
[inv getReturnValue:&returnObj];    // get created object
```

Since 'method' is always 'nil' this approach does not work. Why?
What is the proper way to execute class method via invocation for the above code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is too complicated. You can get an `NSMethodSignature*` object without messing around with the runtime.

```
signature = [NSString methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(stringWithString:)];
```

Comment: Thank you! That is shorter code. However the return result is nil. I tried:
id res = [NSString stringWithString:@"7"];
// 
SEL sel;
NSMethodSignature *sig;
NSInvocation *inv;
Class targetClass;

targetClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSString");
selector   = NSSelectorFromString(@"stringWithString:");

sig = [targetClass methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
[inv setSelector:sel];
id arg = @"7";
[inv setArgument:&arg atIndex:2];
[inv invoke];

id retObj;
[inv getReturnValue:&retObj]
// retObj is nil (I expected @"7")

Comment: @sg7: You're calling `[inv invoke]`, but you never set the target. You either need to set the target, or just use `[inv invokeWithTarget:targetClass]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! [inv invokeWithTarget:targetClass]; corrected my code! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`stringWithString:` is a class method, your code is using `class_getInstanceMethod()`.

Try changing `class_getInstanceMethod()` to `class_getClassMethod()`.

Comment: Thank you! That directly corrected the original code and solved nil **method** problem! However the returnObj is nil and not the expected @"argument"

Comment: As Kevin Ballard pointed out I was missing setting the target as well! After replacing `[inv invoke];` with 
 `[inv invokeWithTarget:targetClass];` and using  `class_getClassMethod()` everything works fine for the original code. Thanks!